# android conditional statement to check if a char is a single quote

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi i am trying to check if two a particular char in a string is a single quote however when i run the code i get no response, the code below should log some text in the console but it is not could you please check my code and see where i am wrong

```
        int p = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.substring(start + 3,end).trim());
        while(p < sb.length()){
            if(sb.charAt(p) == '\''){
                System.out.println("ok    this is a '");
            }
            p++;
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean "you get no response"? What response do you expect? How are you running this code? Is this inside an Android app? Or is it in a `main()` method and run as a regular Java app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can correctly detects a `'`.

There must be something wrong in this:

```java
s.substring(start + 3,end).trim()
```

How do you define `s`, `start` and  `end`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for contributing. Questions for clarification are more appropriate as comments below the question. I think you need to get more reputation points in order to unlock the ability to post comments. Check out the Help section for tips about how to get reputation on the site.

Comment: thanks you were wright i was getting the string from a website and the single quotes were displaying as the open and close single quote ’ .... ‘